# Why does the shiny app works locally but not on server?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

I assume this is a duplicate question (sorry in advance), but I seem not able to resolve this issue. I created a shiny app, which implements a random forest model (party package) returning results with the caret package and visualizing a conditional interference tree with the ctree function. The app works fine locally. However, when I try the publish it no output gets displayed and I get the error *"An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification."* What am I missing here?

The data I use for the model comes from a csv file stored on a dropbox account perhaps this might be the issue? I first used RData and switched to csv file, since this seems to be more often used with shiny.

I followed the steps described on: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/229848967-Why-does-my-app-work-locally-but-not-on-shinyapps-io-, to see if this resoveld the issue. I restarted R and the computer. This did not work.

- There is no code or data stored in the local environment when running locally.
- All packages are loaded via library().
- I load the data via a relative path df <- read.csv("data/df.csv"). All files are stored in a map called shinyapp as app.R and the df.csv in the file data.

The dataset is relatively large so I cannot display it here, but I created a dummy dataset which can be used to run the app.

```
library(shiny)
library(party)
library(caret)
#==============================================================================
#Use dummy dataset in stead of original data
#df <- read.csv("data/df.csv")
#df <- df[df$Taxon %in% names(table(df$Taxon))[table(df$Taxon) >= 50],]

#Create dummy dataset
df  <- data.frame(Sample = 1:500, Taxon = paste0("spec", rbinom(n = 500, 2, 0.5)), SO4 = rnorm(500, 300, 50), pH = rnorm(500, 7, 1), NO3 = rnorm(500, 10, 3))

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Random Forest classification"),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput(inputId = "Spec", label = "Select species:", unique(df$Taxon)),
    selectInput(inputId = "NAN", label = "Select how to use data:", c("All data (Also NAs)", "Complete data (No NAs)")),
    numericInput(inputId = "SO4", label = "Choose value for SO4 (mg/l)", value = median(df$SO4, na.rm = T), min = 0, max = 15000),
    numericInput(inputId = "pH", label = "Choose value for pH", value = median(df$pH, na.rm = T), min = 5, max = 10),
    numericInput(inputId = "NO3", label = "Choose value for NO3 (mg/l)", value = median(df$NO3, na.rm = T), min = 0, max = 50),
    h3("Validation parameters"),
    textOutput("Validation"),
    h3("Voting percentage"),
    textOutput("Votingperc"),
    h3("Remarks"),
    h5("Note that every time the output of the model is different from
       the previous. Samples with the absence of species are more
       prevalent. Therefore, Every time the code is run, samples where a species
       was present are the same. However, samples with absences are randomly 
       selected in equall amount and combines this with samples where the. 
       species was present Further, the random forest model randomly creates 
       trees by bootstrapping the dataset a 100 times. Each time a different 
       model is created. This model is a course estimation, since many more 
       important factors are absent. Validation of the model is performed by 
       training the model on 75% of the dataset and validating on the other 25%. 
       The predicting model is based on the total dataset. The Error: 
       replacement has 1 row, data has 0, occurs when the data for a species
       has no measurements if complete data (without NAs) is used.")),
  mainPanel(plotOutput("Imp"),
            plotOutput("Tree")))

server <- function(input,output){

  #Create model dataset
  modpred           <- reactive({
    present         <- df[df$Taxon == input$Spec,]
    present$Spec    <- 1
    df1             <- df[!duplicated(df$Sample),]
    df1             <- df1[!df1$Sample %in% present$Sample,]

    if(input$NAN == "Complete data (No NAs)"){
      present <- na.omit(present)
      df1     <- na.omit(df1)}

    if((nrow(df)-nrow(present)) > nrow(present)){
      absent        <- df1[sample(1:nrow(df1), nrow(present), replace = F),]}
    else{
      absent        <- df1[sample(1:nrow(df1), nrow(present), replace = T),]}
    absent$Spec     <- 0
    model.data      <- rbind(present, absent)
    model.data$Spec <- as.factor(model.data$Spec)

    #Select 75% as training data
    prestrain       <- present[sample(1:nrow(present), floor(nrow(absent)*0.75), replace = F),]
    abstrain        <- absent[sample(1:nrow(absent), floor(nrow(present)*0.75), replace = F),]
    train.data      <- rbind(prestrain, abstrain)
    train.data$Spec <- as.factor(train.data$Spec)

    #Select the other 25% as validation data
    val.data        <- model.data[!rownames(model.data) %in% rownames(train.data),]

    #Create nice conditional interference tree on all data
    ct              <- party::ctree(Spec~SO4+pH+NO3, data = model.data)

    #Train and validate model
    train.model     <- party::cforest(Spec~SO4+pH+NO3, data=train.data, controls = party::cforest_classical(mtry = 1, ntree = 100))
    validation.mod  <- predict(train.model, newdata = val.data)
    conf.mat.val    <- table(val.data$Spec, predict(train.model, newdata = val.data))
    val.results     <- caret::confusionMatrix(conf.mat.val)
    sumval          <- paste0("AUC=", round(val.results$overall[1],2), " (LCI=", round(val.results$overall[3],2),"; ",
                              "HCI=", round(val.results$overall[4],2), "), ",
                              "Cohen's kappa=", round(val.results$overall[2],2), ", ",
                              "n-validation=", nrow(val.data), ", ", "n-training=", nrow(train.data), ", ", "n-total (model)=", nrow(model.data))

    #Extract relative importance parameters
    relimp          <- as.data.frame(party::varimp(train.model))
    relimp          <- cbind.data.frame(rownames(relimp), relimp)
    colnames(relimp)<-c("Parameter", "Relative importance")
    rownames(relimp)<- NULL
    relimp[,2]      <- relimp$`Relative importance`/sum(relimp$`Relative importance`)*100
    relimp          <- relimp[order(-relimp$`Relative importance`),]

    #Apply model on data input user interface
    model           <- party::cforest(Spec~SO4+pH+NO3, data=model.data, controls = party::cforest_classical(mtry = 1, ntree = 100))
    pred.data       <- setNames(data.frame(as.numeric(input$SO4), as.numeric(input$pH), as.numeric(input$NO3)), c("SO4", "pH", "NO3"))
    pred            <- predict(model, newdata = pred.data, type = "prob")
    prob            <- paste0("Voting percentage (Probability of presence) = ", round(pred$`1`[2]*100,0),"%", ",", 
                              " Majority vote indicates = ", ifelse(pred$`1`[2] > 0.5, "Present", "Absent"))

    combo <- list(Probability = prob, Validation = sumval, Tree = ct, Importance = relimp)})

  output$Votingperc <- renderText({
    combo <- modpred()
    combo$Probability})

  output$Validation <- renderText({
    combo <- modpred()
    combo$Validation})

  output$Imp <- renderPlot({
    combo <- modpred()
    bar   <- combo$Imp
    barplot(bar$`Relative importance`,
            names.arg = bar$Parameter, ylab = "Relative importance (%)")})

  output$Tree <- renderPlot({
    combo <- modpred()
    plot(combo$Tree, inner_panel=node_inner(combo$Tree, pval = FALSE))})

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You will need to copy your dataset into the same directory as your app.R file and make sure it is selected along with all the other files when you click on publish.

Comment: It is in the same directory, if I am correct. The app.R is in shinyapp/app.R and the csv file is in shinyapp/data/df.csv. The df needs to be in the data file, right? It does not need to be shinyapp/df.csv. Or, am I wrong?

Comment: You should call your dataset as follows `read.csv("df.csv")`. It should be in the same folder as app.R.

Comment: Both app.R and df.csv should be in the shinyapp/ folder. I think the problem is that you have df.csv in shinyapp/data/df.csv. Try moving the file.

Comment: No this does not work. I have both objects directly in the shiny file (shinyapp/app.R and shinyapp/df.csv). The funny thing is the ui does show the names of all species and the median (i.e. ```numericInput(inputId = "SO4", label = "Choose value for SO4 (mg/l)", value = median(df$SO4, na.rm = T), min = 0, max = 15000)```) in the server.

Comment: @A4-paper are you able to view your logs and see what the error message says?

Comment: I asked the same question on the rstudio.community forum. In short, I could not see to logs. However, using the```rsconnect::showLogs()``` someone was to extract the results from the example. Apparently the package e1071 was not included in the library (see, https://community.rstudio.com/t/why-does-the-shiny-app-works-locally-but-not-on-server/62123/2). I am not sure if I should keep the question open here. The credits for the solution also go to someone else.